# ASP.Net Core 7 WebAPI Multiple Concurrent Authentication Schemes On Same Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a scenario where my WebAPI needs to accept one of three different Authentication Schemes (OAuth2.0, Basic, Custom) each with their own Authorization Policies.  I want to be able to apply them to each controller in my API without having to duplicate each endpoint.

I have the schemes and policies built out on Startup

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthHandler>(BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { })
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, LegacyAuthHandler>(LegacyAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "preferred_username";
    }, options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    }, JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, true);

services.AddAuthorization(config =>
{
    config.AddPolicy(OAuthConstants.Policy, policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.Requirements.Add(new ScopeAuthorizationRequirement(new List<string> { Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:Scopes") }));
        policy.RequireClaim("env", Configuration.GetValue<string>("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"));
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    });

    config.AddPolicy(BasicAuthenticationDefaults.Policy, policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    });

    config.AddPolicy(LegacyAuthenticationDefaults.Policy, policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(LegacyAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    });
});
```

I have it working currently where each endpoint defines it's specific Scheme and Policy.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Policy = BasicAuthenticationDefaults.Policy)]
[Route("basic")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBasicAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var response = await Library.ListValues.Service.GetListValuesAsync(_context);
        return Ok(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Problem(detail: ex.StackTrace, title: ex.Message);
    }
}

[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = LegacyAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Policy = LegacyAuthenticationDefaults.Policy)]
[Route("legacy")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLegacyAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var response = await Library.ListValues.Service.GetListValuesAsync(_context);
        return Ok(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Problem(detail: ex.StackTrace, title: ex.Message);
    }
}

[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Policy = OAuthConstants.Policy)]
[Route("oauth")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetOAuthAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var response = await Library.ListValues.Service.GetListValuesAsync(_context);
        return Ok(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Problem(detail: ex.StackTrace, title: ex.Message);
    }
}
```

What I would like to do (if possible) is configure my controllers to be able to use any of the 3 on any given endpoint without having to triplicate them.  When I do try this, however, it seems that whichever is defined as the default (since that becomes necessary to define) isn't the one being used for that request, the others aren't tried.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + LegacyAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme+ "," + AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
```

You can read [Use multiple authentication schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-multiple-authentication-schemes) to know more.